# opencv cv::addText exception if no window

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing

I'm using `OpenCV 3.2.0` compiled with `Qt` support and function `cv::addText` to put text on image. Here's the simplest code that reproduces the error

```
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << " Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    Mat image, resized;
    image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file
    namedWindow("test", 1);
    addText(image, "SomeText", Point(5, 27), fontQt("Times"));
    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
    imshow("Display window", image); // Show our image inside it.
    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error

> /home/vitaly/CLionProjects/opencvTest/cmake-build-debug/opencvTest
>   /home/vitaly/Pictures/img.jpg OpenCV Error: Null pointer (NULL
>   guiReceiver (please create a window)) in cvAddText, file
>   /home/vitaly/Documents/opencv/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp,
>   line 114 terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'cv::Exception'   what(): 
>   /home/vitaly/Documents/opencv/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:114:
>   error: (-27) NULL guiReceiver (please create a window) in function
>   cvAddText

which goes away if I add

```
namedWindow("test", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
```

before addText.

However, I cannot understand why would qt or opencv need an opened window for that ? I don't need to display the image, I'm only using it to put text on image and then save it, I don't want to create any windows.

So here's my questions

1. Why window is required for that ?
2. Is there a way around it ? (To not create windows)

Comment: I guess you should try [putText](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext)

Comment: I've tried. `putText` gives very bad quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/7f2ac764ae31dbea97e45f565f555ce60a799067/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp):

```
CV_IMPL void cvAddText(const CvArr* img, const char* text, CvPoint org, CvFont* font)
{
    if (!guiMainThread)
        CV_Error( CV_StsNullPtr, "NULL guiReceiver (please create a window)" );

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(guiMainThread,
        "putText",
        autoBlockingConnection(),
        Q_ARG(void*, (void*) img),
        Q_ARG(QString,QString::fromUtf8(text)),
        Q_ARG(QPoint, QPoint(org.x,org.y)),
        Q_ARG(void*,(void*) font));
}
```

addText requires a gui thread. as the actual drawing happens in that thread. No thread, no function, no drawing...

Why is it like that? Well because it made sense to somebody I guess.

It's open source, feel free to code your own workaround. Otherwise use OpenCV's putText.

Comment: Mind that there should be no interthread problem with `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(guiMainThread,
        "putText",
        Qt::QueuedConnection, // queued connection
        Q_ARG(void*, (void*) img),
        Q_ARG(QString,QString::fromUtf8(text)),
        Q_ARG(QPoint, QPoint(org.x,org.y)),
        Q_ARG(void*,(void*) font));`  so you could remove `if (!guiMainThread) {}`

Answer (score 0):

`puttext` should work fine as already suggested.

If you're looking for more powerful gui formatting options, you can use the CanvasCV library which blends into the OpenCV main loop.

Here is a tutorial about using its [Text widget](https://sagi-z.github.io/CanvasCV/doc/html/tutscreentext.html#screentext_s2_3).

Here is another one about auto [centering text with layouts](https://sagi-z.github.io/CanvasCV/doc/html/tutlayouts.html#layouts_s1).